# How do I make a backtick with a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My android bluetooth keyboard doesn't have a backtick, but it has function buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: finally:

hold Function + L